# Totalize and Relationships in depth

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm using neo4j 3.5 community edition and trying totalize and get hops from a specific node. I'm running to totalize(its working):

```
MATCH (p:Person{id:123})-[r]->(m)
RETURN p,count(distinct(r.idSale)) as qtd,sum(r.value) as value,type(r) as type,r.seg as segment,m
```

How I get hops when its totalize?? I'm trying something like these (not working):

```
MATCH (p:Person{id:123})-[r]->(m)-[r2*2]->(m2)
RETURN p,count(distinct(r.idSale)) as qtd,sum(r.value) as value,type(r),m,count(distinct(r2.idSale)) as qtd2,sum(r2.value) as t
```

> error : Type mismatch: expected Any, Map, Node, Relationship, Point,
>   Duration, Date, Time, LocalTime, LocalDateTime or DateTime but was
>   List (line 1, column 149 (offset: 148))

My graph is like this:
[image]
I'm trying:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since `[r2*2]` specifies a [variable length relationship](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/clauses/match/#varlength-rels) pattern, `r2` is a *list* of relationships.

Here is one way to get what it *seems* you want:

```
MATCH (p:Person{id:123})-[r]->(m), path=(m)-[*2]->(m2)
RETURN p,count(distinct(r.idSale)) as qtd,sum(r.value) as value,type(r),m,
  SIZE(apoc.coll.toSet([r2 IN RELATIONSHIPS(path) | r2.idSale])) AS qtd2,
  REDUCE(s = 0, r2 IN RELATIONSHIPS(path) | s + r2.value) AS total2,
  [r2 IN RELATIONSHIPS(path) | TYPE(r2)] AS types2,
  m2
```

This query uses the APOC function [apoc.coll.toSet](https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/apoc/current/data-structures/collection-list-functions/) to get a distinct list. Also, it returns a list of relationship types in `types2`.

Comment: I'm trying totalize in depth and still have nodes conections like picture above.